# SQL Server Make Tracks or Path of Parent has many child

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I have an `Activity` table :

```
ActivityID       ActivityName
-----------------------------
 1                A1
 2                A2
 3                A3
 4                A4
 5                A5
 6                A6
 7                A7
 8                A8
 9                A9
 10               A10
```

and related it in another table with parent child relationship as:

```
ParentActivityID     ChildActivityID
-------------------------------------
 1                     2
 1                     3
 2                     4
 2                     5
 3                     6 
 4                     7
 5                     7
 6                     8
 7                     9
 8                     9
 9                     10
```

I want to write a SQL query which will make it in tracks depend on how many `childActivity` in one `parentActivity`  like :

```
ActivityID    TrackGroup
-------------------------
 1             1
 2             1
 4             1
 7             1
 9             1
 10            1
 1             2
 2             2
 5             2
 7             2
 9             2
 10            2
 1             3
 3             3
 6             3
 8             3
 9             3
 10            3
```

using sql sever 2008 r

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem?  Please post some sample code that you have tried.

Comment: is this Sql server 2012+

Comment: sorry I forgot this is sql server 2008 r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the slowest query on the planet depending on your table sizes, but it does what you're asking for and I have no way of testing the performance really.

But create test data.

```
CREATE TABLE Activity
    ([ActivityID] int, [ActivityName] varchar(3))
;
INSERT INTO Activity
    ([ActivityID], [ActivityName])
VALUES
    (1, 'A1'),    (2, 'A2'),    (3, 'A3'),    (4, 'A4'),    (5, 'A5'),
    (6, 'A6'),    (7, 'A7'),    (8, 'A8'),    (9, 'A9'),    (10, 'A10')
;
CREATE TABLE RelatedActivity
    ([ParentActivityID] int, [ChildActivityID] int)
;
INSERT INTO RelatedActivity
    ([ParentActivityID], [ChildActivityID])
VALUES
    (1, 2),    (1, 3),    (2, 4),    (2, 5),    (3, 6),    (4, 7),
    (5, 7),    (6, 8),    (7, 9),    (8, 9),    (9, 10)
;
```

Just assumed you might run this for 1 activity so I created a variable and set it to the first ActivityID

```
DECLARE @ActivityID INT = 1
```

I then used a recursive cte to get me the hierarchy.  I add a "Path" field which just concatenates the current ID with the previous IDs.

Then using the ROW_NUMBER function in SQL 2008 and ordering by the `PATH`, I can get the next `PATH`.

Then i can compare the LEN of the current path and the LEN of the next path to see if a new path will start next, if so then give me the current path.  Or if the next PATH is NULL also get it.

Then i use a string split function to convert the remaining paths into rows.

```
--Get hierarchy
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT  [ActivityID], NULL ParentActivityID, CAST([ActivityID] AS VARCHAR(255)) [Path] 
    FROM    Activity WHERE [ActivityID] = @ActivityID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ra.[ChildActivityID], ra.[ParentActivityID], CAST([Path] + '.' + CAST(ra.[ChildActivityID] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255))
    FROM    Activity a
    JOIN    RelatedActivity ra ON a.[ActivityID] = ra.[ChildActivityID]
    JOIN    cte ON ra.[ParentActivityID] = cte.[ActivityID]
)

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Path]) Rn 
INTO #tempHierarchy 
FROM cte 

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS ActivityID,
       Rn AS TrackGroup
FROM
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Path]) Rn, 
            CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE([Path],'.','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM
        #tempHierarchy t1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Path] [Next], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Path]) - 1 Rn  FROM #tempHierarchy) t2 ON t1.Rn = t2.Rn
    WHERE
        [NEXT] IS NULL OR LEN([Next]) < LEN([Path])
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b877d/6)

Comment: thanks for help but I forgot to type that i'm using MS SQL server 2008 r

Comment: Thank you very much it works :) but can not save as dbo.view

Comment: @Beaudeep if you want to use this in a view. you just need to use a CTE where the `SELECT INTO #tempHierarchy` part is..

Comment: yes I did thank you :) 

[  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Path]) Rn 
INTO #tempHierarchy 
FROM cte   ]                  

replaced         
    [   , tempHierarchy AS
(SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Path]) Rn
  FROM    cte)  ]

Comment: if you don't mind,  I post your answer in other site and I mentioned your name